# "No improvement whatsoever" reason in the reject dialog (documentation)

Tags: feature-request, bug, documentation

There is no such option. I have needed it couple of times in my first documentation reviews.

[image]

Comment: Should have been used here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/76362

Comment: Is there another way to propose this on Meta? I wonder why this request has so few supporters though nobody explains what may be wrong with it. I miss this option very often, too.

Comment: +1 "No improvement whatsoever" is already in QA review, so why not in Docs? [Where it would be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/139451)